# Can not upgrade Ubuntu server 19.04 to 19.10 ('ubuntu-minimal' could not be located)

Tags: server, upgrade, 19.04, do-release-upgrade, 19.10

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,319 kB]
Fetched 1,320 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'eoan.tar.gz' against 'eoan.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'eoan.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
Hit http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu disco InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu disco InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Updating repository information

Third party sources disabled

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool
or your package manager.

To continue please press [ENTER]

Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Invalid package information

After updating your package information, the essential package
'ubuntu-minimal' could not be located. This may be because you have
no official mirrors listed in your software sources, or because of
excessive load on the mirror you are using. See /etc/apt/sources.list
for the current list of configured software sources.
In the case of an overloaded mirror, you may want to try the upgrade
again later.


Restoring original system state

Aborting
```

Comment: So, did you follow the hint and tried changing your apt mirror ? `This may be because you have
no official mirrors listed in your software sources, or because of
excessive load on the mirror you are using`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using [unsupported Ubuntu interim release](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle).

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and add the following lines:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
```

and remove the lines which doesn't work.

Then run: `sudo apt-get update` again.

And try to do distribution upgrade again: `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Source: [How To: Fix apt update in Ubuntu 19.04](https://www.unixtutorial.org/fix-apt-update-ubuntu-19-04/).

Answer (score 0):

For [EOL process](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades), I ran into this error with the upgrade tool and spent some time working through it.

After inspecting `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log`, I realised the mirror was defaulting to local region mirror then failing. This logic happens in the `DistUpgradeController.py` near the end of the script.

Turned out I had to edit the mirror paths to force the `mirror.cfg` script to use the `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`. You can comment out the other preceeding paths so it forces it.

Voila!